# Create objects of array using a timer

Tags: java, for-loop, timer

I am trying to create objects of array using a timer and, each customer must be printed by 'cst', So my problem here is all the customers including the 1 on the constructor are printed at same time and my code does terminated as well, and at the end I have to use the customer object

```
class Customers  extends TimerTask{

    int cst;

    Customers(int i) {

        cst = i;
        System.out.println("A Customer# "+cst+ " is added ");//should increment customer by one
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //creating 10 objects of customers
        Customers[] cstm = new Customers[10];

        for(int count =0; count < cstm.length; count++){

            cstm[count] = new Customers(count+1);

        }

    }
}
```

This is what I have on the main class

```
public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Timer timer = new Timer();

      timer.schedule(new Customers(1), 0,5000);
    }

}
```

Comment: why is costumer a child of a timer? that looks weird

Comment: Your Timer never stops under any condition. Why are you expecting it to terminate?

Comment: Could you please describe the expected behaviour in a better way?

Comment: @cricket_007 I did tried to use a control statement to cancel timer but it ignores it

Comment: @Maia results should be from 1 to 10 and must be printed every 5 seconds

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ this show me a better way

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add what you see vs what you **want** to see